# Hanging preposition (if it's how it's called)

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Consider this, for example:

> Given the country's strong cultural ties (with) and economic dependence on Russia, many candidates tried to gain Moscow's support.

Do I need that 'with'?

Comment: split the sentence into two independent sentences with the same preposition. If it reads grammatical, you go with just one preposition. If one sentence is incomplete/meaningless you obviously need to include the other preposition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need a preposition there.

What you have is a phrase where the country is related to Russia in two ways:

- Strong cultural ties with...
- Economic dependence on...

If the term and preposition used in each phrase were the same, you could get away with only using one preposition in the combined sentence:

> Given the country's strong [cultural and linguistic] [ties with] Russia...

But because you are using two different prepositions, you need to list each one:

> Given the country's [strong cultural ties with] and [economic dependence on] Russia...

(If you leave out the "with," it sounds like you're saying the country has "strong cultural ties **on**, and economic dependence **on**, Russia. This is not correct usage of the phrase "ties with.")